# $f$ defined on $[1,\infty )$ is uniformly continuous. Then $\exists M>0$ s.t. $\frac{|f(x)|}{x}\le M$ for $x\ge 1$.

Tags: calculus, continuity

$f$ defined on $[1,\infty )$ is uniformly continuous. Then $\exists M>0$ s.t. $\frac{|f(x)|}{x}\le M$ for $x\ge 1$.

I know f uniformly continuous $\implies \forall\varepsilon > 0s.t.\forall x,y\in [1,\infty)$,
$$|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon \space\space\forall |x-y|<\delta$$

By Mean value theorem, $\exists c\in (x,y)\forall x,y\in [1,\infty)$ such that

$$\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y}=f'(c)$$

$$\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}=|f'(c)|<M$$ for some $M>0$

$$|f(x)-f(y)|<M|x-y|<M\delta $$

How can I get an expression for $|f(x)|/x$?

Comment: Is $f$ differentiable?

Comment: It doesn't specify, only that $f$ is defined on that interval and is uniformly continuous.

Comment: So you cannot argue by mean value theorem.

Comment: you're right.. so i can only use epsilon delta argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $f(1)=0$ for the moment. Let $\epsilon=1$. Then there is $\delta $ such that

$$|f(x) - f(y)| < 1$$

whenever $|x-y|\leq\delta$. Let $x\in [1, \infty)$. The idea is that you chop the interval $[1, x]$ into small intervals so that you can apply the above inequality. Now there is $n\in \mathbb N$ such that

$$1 + n\delta \leq x < 1 + (n+1)\delta,$$

(Just chopping the intervals) Then write $x_m = 1+ m\delta$,

$$\begin{split} |f(x)| &= |f(x)-f(1)| \\
&\leq |f(x) - f(x_{n})| +  |f(x_{n}) - f(x_{n-1})| + \cdots \\
&\ \ \ +|f(x_2) - f(x_1)|+ |f(x_1) - f(1)| \\
&\leq 1 + 1 + \cdots + 1 = n+1 <2n\\
&< \frac{2}{\delta}(1+ \delta n)\\
&\leq Mx\ .
\end{split}$$

By letting $M = \frac{2}{\delta}$ (note that $\delta $ is fixed). Thus

$$\frac{|f(x)|}{x} \leq M\ .$$

In general, if $f(x) \neq 0$, then letting $g(x) = f(x) - f(1)$, then $g$ is also uniformly continuous. Thus there is $M$ such that

$$\frac{|f(x) - f(1)|}{x} = \frac{|g(x)|}{x} \leq M$$

which implies

$$\frac{|f(x)|}{x} \leq M+ \frac{|f(1)|}{x} \leq M + |f(1)|\ .$$

Comment: can you please explain why we must assume f(1)=0? Is the second general part of the proof necessary (g(x)) can we simply do the top part, and that has proved everything that we want to show?

Comment: You don't have to assume $f(1)=0$. You can just work on $|f(x) -f(1)|$ instead of $|f(x)|$. @Lydia

Comment: Is f(1)= 0 necessary for the first part of the proof to be correct though?

Comment: Assuming $f(1)=0$ in the first place just help people better understand the technique. Like I said, you do not need to assume that. @Lydia

Comment: nice explanation: but can you explain  the process of " chopping off" the given  interval a bit more ?

Comment: ah! I get it now, it is $ [1,\infty)= [1,1+\delta] ∪ [1+ \delta, 1+2\delta] ∪...$.

Comment: shouldn't it be $f(1)$ instead of $f(0)$ in 3rd paragraph?

Comment: @shrey You are right (and edited).